# Failure sending mail: The transport failed to connect to the server

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have numerous SSRS reports. Most with subscriptions. All of the existing subscriptions are working fine but I am getting an error when I try and set up a new subscription. The example attached shows a working and a failed subscription. Can anyone offer any advice on this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are all of the recipients internal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would mean that SSRS failed to connect to the SMTP server to send the subscription. This seems like an issue with your mail server rather than SSRS. Please make sure the mail server is up and running.

Additionally please take a look at the configurations for reporting services:  Within Reporting Services Configuration click on Email Settings.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the SSRS was failing to connect to SMTP. Antivirus was the cause.